# Overrides not passing from lambda to ECS via State functions

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, containers, amazon-ecs, aws-step-functions

I have a step function that is calling a lambda, which does some processing, and gets the id of the job that needs to be processed by the ecs runtask.

What I am trying to do is to pass the job Id as containerOverride so that each run a different Id can be passed to the ecs Run task.

Here is the dummy lambda Output:

```
Test Event Name
dummyTest

Response
{
  "containerOverrides": " [ { \"name\": \"getFileTask\", \"environment\": [ { \"name\": \"name1\", \"value\": \"123\" }, { \"name\": \"DATE\", \"value\": \"1234-12-12\" }, { \"name\": \"SCRIPT\", \"value\": \"123456\" } ] } ] "
}
```

Dummy Lambda Code:

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # TODO implement
    print("Success")
    
    overridden_Text = ' [ { "name": "getFileTask", "environment": [ { "name": "name1", "value": "123" }, { "name": "DATE", "value": "1234-12-12" }, { "name": "SCRIPT", "value": "123456" } ] } ] '
    
    return{
        'containerOverrides': overridden_Text
          

        }
```

Here is the record when the ECS run task is triggered(TaskStateEntered) from the step function:

```
{
  "name": "ECS RunTask",
  "input": {
    "containerOverrides": " [ { \"name\": \"getFileTask\", \"environment\": [ { \"name\": \"name1\", \"value\": \"123\" }, { \"name\": \"DATE\", \"value\": \"1234-12-12\" }, { \"name\": \"SCRIPT\", \"value\": \"123456\" } ] } ] "
  },
  "inputDetails": {
    "truncated": false
  }
}
```

The issue is that when the run task enters the TaskSubmitted stage:

```
"LastStatus": "PROVISIONING",
        "LaunchType": "FARGATE",
        "Memory": "4096",
        "Overrides": {
          "ContainerOverrides": [
            {
              "Command": [],
              "Environment": [],
              "EnvironmentFiles": [],
              "Name": "getFileTask",
              "ResourceRequirements": []
            }
          ],
          "InferenceAcceleratorOverrides": []
        },
        "PlatformFamily": "Linux",
        "PlatformVersion": "1.4.0",
        "StartedBy": "AWS Step Functions",
```

For what ever reasons the Environment variable is not being pushed from lambda output to the Container as launch override. Is there something that I am doing incorrectly ?

UPDATED: Snippet of statemachine
[image]

Thanks

Comment: How are you mapping the step input to the ECS task settings? Please include the state machine code in your question. For example if you look at the official documentation here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/connect-ecs.html you will see an example of using input values in the `Overrides: ContainerOverrides` configuration values.

Comment: Hey, for the test run I am using the console to create the statemachine. I have attached the snippet above(Updated section) on how I am mapping the Input to Run Task. POssibly I am doing that incorrectly ?

Comment: You are configuring the input, so the values are *available* to use inside the ECS task definition, but you still need to actually use them inside the task definition now. Also, it doesn't matter that you are creating the state machine through the console, you can still get to the JSON representation of your state machine through the console, and then include that in your question.

Comment: Hey Mark, Sorry some newbie questions here- I got the part about task definition, are you saying that at time of task creation using the CDK, I have an option to specify the --override at execution and then the --override should get the $.Input ?

Comment: No sorry, I said "Task Definition", while what I should have said was the "Step Function ECS Run Task Configuration". You've made the variables available via input, but Step Functions isn't going to magically map those to some nested property of the task configuration, you still have to wire up those variables to the task overrides inside the ECS Run Task configuration in the Step Functions state machine.

Comment: What is the source code of your state machine in json?

Comment: Hey apologies for the delay in responding. I was able to figure this out from Marcs comments. For everyone who is planning to use CDK:  container_override = _stepfunctions_tasks.ContainerOverride( .... ) Then in the _stepfunctions_tasks.EcsRunTask  add container_overrides=[container_override] parameter. This basically tells container to use the override parameter when runnning. Also a side note, in the container override do - value=_stepfunctions.JsonPath.string_at("$.job_id") if you want to see following in json "Value.$" otherwise the actual value of parameter is not passed and the text is.

Comment: Admin please mark Marks comment as the solution. Ty